# Excel multiply days and hours with a factor

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I would like to calculate the time span betweeen two dates with excel and multiply the amount of days with a factor - like  2 d and 10 h * 5$

Its easy to get the days and hours by just substracting in two cells B-A and format one cells with CUSTOM dd and one CUSTOM hh.

But apparently I can not just multiply the values by a decimal factor.

Do you know what to do?

Comment: Are you using the equivalent decimal that's converted out of time (/60, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to apply formatting in the same way to your multiplied cells.

[image]

A5 and A9 have custom format dd, and B5 and B9 have custom format hh.

[image: After]

Answer (score 0):

So what result do you expect? If the difference is 2 days 10 hours and you multiply by 5 that's

12 days and 2 hours

best to avoid `dd` format because it only counts up to 31, try this formula

`=INT((B2-A2)*5)&" d "&TEXT((B2-A2)*5,"h:mm")`